# Why are my Wikimedia pages are showing a LUA error?

Tags: mediawiki, lua, mediawiki-extension

I downloaded and installed media wiki and imported some xml files from wikipedia's special:export.

I enabled scribunto and parserfunctions and enabled all other necessary extensions.

But all the pages are showing alot of this error:

> :Lua error: Cannot create process: proc_open(/dev/null): Failed to open stream: Operation not permitted

I chmod 777 the lua file and all contents of the directory /extensions/Scribunto/ as well as 777 to /dev/null in vain.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The post
[Newbie trying to get infoboxes to work. Getting Lua error.](https://www.reddit.com/r/mediawiki/comments/14pnpgb/newbie_trying_to_get_infoboxes_to_work_getting/)
sounds remarkably like your problem:

> I've followed the instructions for setting up infoboxes. However, I'm
> getting the following error and googling the solution hasn't worked
> out:
>
> ```
> Lua error: Cannot create process: proc_open(/dev/null): Failed to open stream: Operation not permitted
> ```

The analysis by the poster of the problem says that it's caused
by the `open_basedir` restriction in `php.ini` which you should
remove.

Try this:
Open the file `php.ini` in a text-editor and search for the string
`open_basedir`. Comment this line out by adding a semi-colon (`;`)
at its beginning and restart PHP. Or you should perhaps give it
another value, but I don't have your environment for testing.